# How Do I Retrieve Pictures From From Audiovox CDM-8910BM?

Tags: phone

I have some pictures on my phone, however it only gives the option to upload via an online album.
The phone is 10 years old.

Someone said that you can use a data cable and transfer the picture to PC. I have a data cable. I connect it to the computer, but nothing happens. If I 'lsusb' in the terminal, it detects the phone.
Does the kernel keep old drivers, or are the only present on older OS?
What I mean is do they ever remove drivers from the kernel?
Will I need an old kernel or are the latest ones adequate?
I'm sorry if I don't make sense. I have Autism, and my communication skills aren't the best.

I found an app called BitPim, which stopped being supported in 13.10, so I booted into 12.04 (since it is still supported), and used that however it did not detect my phone but was able to give information off about it, which was weird.

I also have Vista installed on another computer, and also working with that. It is important that I retrieve my old photos.

Comment: Hi, pls provide us with a little bit more Info, what is the return of 'lsusb'?

Comment: Also pls be more precise in what "however it did not detect my phone but was able to give information off about it", means, copy command returns or post screenshots, will make it easier to help.

Comment: did you have a look at this: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/211974/Audiovox-Cdm-8910.html?page=35#manual and perhaps here https://www.manualslib.com/manual/211974/Audiovox-Cdm-8910.html?page=39#manual

Comment: LSUSB: Bus 003 Device 006: ID 106c:2101 Curitel Communications, Inc. AudioVox 8900 Cell Phone

I mean when I chose to 'detect phone' via BitPim, it would recognise it, there was a page with some things that I could click on, and two of them brough up some info about it. That was on Ubuntu 12.04, which I had used from a live CD. I'm trying to boot it up again so I can post a screenshot.

I have the PDF manual. Thank you.